# OCR using UWP (Windows 10)

Tags: vba, uwp, ocr

I've done numerous searching but can't find any examples of what I'm trying to do.

As per this MS article, Windows 10 has built in OCR using the Universal Windows Platform.

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.ocr.ocrengine

Anyone know if this API can be called directly via VBA? (loads of examples of how to do so with Visual Studio but that's not what I'm after).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/OCR) example?

Comment: Thanks Vijay, yes I had a look however it refers to Visual Studio and I'm trying to do this excluively in VBA (if possible).

Comment: I don't know VB to help you. Maybe [this](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/vb-net-imaging/ocr-sdk/) post may help you.

Comment: Thanks again Vijay however that's using another SDK.  I'm specifically interested in using the UWP as it's available on all Win 10 machines therefore makes the portability of anything referencing it robust.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/) covers generally how to use UWP from existing desktop applications (including a VB6 example). Essentially, you have to use the Desktop Bridge to make functions that you can call from VB6. It doesn't look like that class has the `DualApiPartition` attribute which means that [it will require a package identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api?redirectedfrom=MSDN#both).